# Separation into different objects fails

Tags: objects, transforms, faces

For practice I am trying to model an object and need to duplicate and move a face (similar to the way it's done in blender guru's doughnut tutorial for the icing).

So I marked the faces I want to duplicate:
[image]

...used shift + D and then moved the duplicated face:
[image]

...and then used P and "selection" to make its own object out of it:
[image]

However, as you can see in the last image, the separation somehow fails. Its marked in red and I cannot do any transformation or so to the new object.

Does anybody know what's wrong here?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: did you release the object after shift D or right clik?

Comment: Once separated. Go back to object mode, unselect everything (click in a large empty space) then re-select the object you want to modify.

Comment: "*However, as you can see in the last image, the separation somehow fails.*" The last image shows two cylinder objects in the outliner, which specifically indicates the opposite

Comment: After you separate (P), be sure to exit Edit mode on Cylinder.  Otherwise you won't be able to select anything in Cylinder.001.   So 1) Separate; 2) exit Edit mode; 3) select Cylinder.001; 4) enter Edit mode on that selected object; 5) make sub-object edits.   Forgetting to exit Edit mode is the bane of my existence!

Comment: James and Christopher, thanks! That solved it!!

Comment: @ChristopherBennett, since your answer was first, I'll click accept if you post answer. Thanks to james, too, though!

Comment: It's ok. You posted an answer to the question - that's all that matters. Don't forget, you can "accept" your own answer by clicking the checkmark. That way others know it's the correct solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @james-t and @Christopher-Bannett wrote in the comments, edit mode needs to be exited first and then re-entered under the new object.

Thanks guys!!